# Batchfile: How can I just display the folder names without showing the entire path

Tags: list, batch-file

I have some code to display options to allow the user to choose from. Currently the code displays the entire path. Is there anyway to just display the folders at the end of the path?

Here is my code so far

```
:incorrect1
@echo 3. Select a folder from the list below
echo[
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set Index=1
for /d %%D in ("C:\Projects\Google\Automation\TestResults\*") do (
  set "Subfolders[!Index!]=%%D"
  set /a Index+=1
)
set /a UBound=Index-1

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%i in (1,1,%UBound%) do echo %%i. !Subfolders[%%i]!
:choiceloop
set /p Choice=Your choice: 
if "%Choice%"=="" goto chioceloop
if %Choice% LSS 1 goto choiceloop
if %Choice% GTR %UBound% goto choiceloop

set Subfolder=!Subfolders[%Choice%]!
echo[
set /P c=Are you happy with your selection[Y/N]?

if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :incorrect1
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :happy so move on1

:happy so move on1
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but the second `setlocal` is superfluous. It's not a switch (unfortunately) and establishes a new "frame" that needs to be closed (by reaching a matching `endlocal` or end-of-file) The available nesting of such frames is limited. Further, `if "%Choice%"=="" goto chioceloop` contains a typo. Note that `set /p` does not alter the variable if simply `enter` is keyed, so if the variable already contains a value, that value will be unaltered, not cleared. You should clear the value explicitly before the `set /p`. Note `choice` is a command, hence a poor variable-name.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `%%~nxD` to get the name and extension of the file, without drive or path information.

```
  set "Subfolders[!Index!]=%%~nxD"
```

There are a number of modifiers that can be applied to FOR variables that are analogous to modifiers that can be applied to parameters like `%1`, etc.

You can read about it from the command line by executing `help for` or `for /?`.